# How to pass data in <a> tag redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I submit a form to my controller with a POST request. The POST returns multiple values to me, and those values are displayed using knockout in function projectionModel.

```
    $("#calculate").bind("click", function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var model = self.closest("form").serialize() + '&ProductId=' + 1;

        $.post("@Url.Action("Projection", "Financial")", model).done(function (json) {
            projectionModel.deposit(json.model.deposit);
            projectionModel.payment(json.model.payment);
            projectionModel.duration(json.model.duration);
            projectionModel.optimistic(json.items["Optimistic"]);
            // Some more data
```

The POST is answered by FinancialController, and returns JSON.

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Projection(ProjectionViewModel model)
        {
// some logic
        return Json(new
        {
            model,
            items,
            per10KDriving,
            per10KEating,
            per10KShowering
        });
}
```

After the values are displayed, I use an a tag with permalink-path to redirect to the next page.

```
            <a class="btn btn-large" data-="" permalink-path="purchase">
                Purchase now
            </a>
```

I would like to receive this Json string in my redirected page purchase. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can either replace the `a` tag with a form containing the values, or you can url encode the json and add it to your path i.e. `<a class="btn btn-large" href="purchase?model=%7B%20%20%22somedata%22%3A%20%22value%22%20%7D">Purchase now</a>`

Comment: @Grax32 How would I get the returned JSON (as JS) in my a tag?